# Insert an LLVM instruction using insertAfter()

Tags: c++, c, llvm, bytecode

I'm new to LLVM, and I'm doing some experiments on it such as inserting an instruction.

My `main.c` is shown below:

```
int foo(int e, int a) {
  int b = a + 1;
  int c = b * 2;
  b = e << 1;
  int d = b / 4;
  return c * d;
}
```

I use the command below to generate the LLVM bytecode

```
clang-12 -O0 -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -emit-llvm -c main.c -o main.bc
opt-12 -S -mem2reg main.bc -o main.ll
```

The bytecode is

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @foo(i32 %0, i32 %1) #0 {
  %3 = add nsw i32 %1, 1
  %4 = mul nsw i32 %3, 2
  %5 = shl i32 %0, 1
  %6 = sdiv i32 %5, 4
  %7 = mul nsw i32 %4, %6
  ret i32 %7
}
```

And I use the code to insert an instruction after the first instruction:

```
bool runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &B) {
    // get the first and second instruction
Instruction &Inst1st = *B.begin();
Instruction *NewInst = BinaryOperator::Create(
        Instruction::Add, Inst1st.getOperand(0), Inst1st.getOperand(0));
NewInst->insertAfter(&Inst1st);
...
}
```

After I run this pass, the bytecode is changed to

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @foo(i32 %0, i32 %1) #0 {
  %3 = add nsw i32 %1, 1
  %4 = add i32 %1, %1
  %5 = mul nsw i32 %4, 2
  %6 = shl i32 %0, 1
  %7 = sdiv i32 %6, 4
  %8 = mul nsw i32 %5, %7
  ret i32 %8
}
```

It seems that the inserted instruction is equal to `b = a + a;`, so the instruction   `%4 = mul nsw i32 %3, 2` is changed to `%5 = mul nsw i32 %4, 2`. I cannot understand the reason. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, `NewInst->insertAfter(&Inst1st);` makes from the block

```
int b = a + 1;
int c = b * 2;
```

the following block

```
int b = a + 1, a + a;
int c = b * 2;
```

therefore `b` drops off the previous value `%3` and gets the new value `%4` and further `mul` uses that new value of `b`.

Comment: I got it, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to use "insertAfter()" in a way that does not cause such side effect (i.e. to create a standalone instruction)? If it is not possible, then using "insertAfter()" seems to require a lot of care.

Answer (score 1):

**I could not reproduce your output bytecode**. Any chance you forgot to mention something?

This question made me curious enough to try it myself.

I used the same c file as in the question and I used the same commands to generate the LLVM bytecode, the only difference was I used LLVM 16.

As expected I got the same initial bytecode as yours:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @foo(i32 noundef %e, i32 noundef %a) #0 {
entry:
  %add = add nsw i32 %a, 1
  %mul = mul nsw i32 %add, 2
  %shl = shl i32 %e, 1
  %div = sdiv i32 %shl, 4
  %mul1 = mul nsw i32 %mul, %div
  ret i32 %mul1
}
```

I wrote the following function pass using the code you provided to insert the add instruction after the first instruction:

```
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
...
PreservedAnalyses FuncPass::run(Function &F, FunctionAnalysisManager &AM) {
  for (auto &B : F) {
    Instruction &Inst1st = *B.begin();
    Instruction *NewInst = BinaryOperator::Create(
        Instruction::Add, Inst1st.getOperand(0), Inst1st.getOperand(0));
    NewInst->insertAfter(&Inst1st);
  }
  return PreservedAnalyses::none();
}
```

Then I ran the bytecode through the above function pass but the result I got was **different from yours**:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @foo(i32 noundef %e, i32 noundef %a) #0 {
entry:
  %add = add nsw i32 %a, 1
  %0 = add i32 %a, %a
  %mul = mul nsw i32 %add, 2
  %shl = shl i32 %e, 1
  %div = sdiv i32 %shl, 4
  %mul1 = mul nsw i32 %mul, %div
  ret i32 %mul1
}
```

My result bytecode, similar to yours, contains the new add instruction right after the first instruction, **but despite your output bytecode, the result of this new add instruction does not replace the usage of variable `b` in the next instruction**.